# JSON output includes literal \n rather than line breaks

Tags: python, json

How can the JSON output be formatting in a way that doesn't include the \n text, and instead shows these as new lines as intended? This is what the saved output file looks like:

[image]

But, this is how it looks when I use print, which is what it should look like:

[image]

```
import requests
import json

def get_all_time_entries():

    url_address = "***"  
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "***",
        "api-version": "2020-01-31"
    }

    # find out total number of pages
    r = requests.get(url=url_address, headers=headers).json()
    total_pages = 605

    # results will be appended to this list
    all_time_entries = []

    # loop through all pages and return JSON object
    for page in range(1, total_pages):

        url = "***"+str(page)              
        response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()        
        all_time_entries.append(response)       
        page += 1

    # prettify JSON
    data = json.dumps(all_time_entries, sort_keys=True, indent=4)



    return data



#print(get_all_time_entries())

with open('appointmentsHistory.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # note that I use dump method, not dumps
    json.dump(get_all_time_entries(), f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Comment: `data` is already JSON. It looks like you're using `json.dump(data, file)`. This double-encodes it. You should just use `file.write(data)`

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json.dumps()` transforms the `data` dictionary into a string, and then `json.dump()` writes *the JSON representation of that string* to the file.

To resolve, remove `json.dumps()` from the `get_all_time_entries()` method. `json.dump()` will take the dictionary in directly and transform it into a JSON string for you.

```py
import requests
import json

def get_all_time_entries():
    url_address = "***"  
    headers = {
        "Authorization": "***",
        "api-version": "2020-01-31"
    }

    # find out total number of pages
    r = requests.get(url=url_address, headers=headers).json()
    total_pages = 605

    # results will be appended to this list
    all_time_entries = []

    # loop through all pages and return JSON object
    for page in range(1, total_pages):

        url = "***"+str(page)              
        response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).json()        
        all_time_entries.append(response)       
        page += 1

    return data

with open('appointmentsHistory.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    # note that I use dump method, not dumps
    json.dump(get_all_time_entries(), f, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

`json.dump()` takes an object, you seem to be passing it a JSON-like string.